# Rails 3.1 + ActiveAdmin GEM css/stylesheet conflict?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin

I must be missing something really simple, but I could not find anyone else with the problem. 
Basically, Rails 3.1 merges all the .css files into application.css. After I installed ActiveAdmin, ActiveAdmin's CSS are also merged into application.css, causes conflict and overrides my stylesheet.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I removed *= require_tree . from application.css and added each other css individually. Not sure whether this is the best way, but it works.

Answer (score 3):

I solved it by adding the generated active_admin css and js in the vendor directory..

- vendor/assets/stylesheets/active_admin.css.scss
- vendor/assets/active_admin.js